# Rewrite URL with port in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help rewriting the following URL:
`http://example.com:7071/hotels_index/1`
to this:
`http://example.com/hotels_index_1.json`

So far I've got:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)_([^/]+)_([0-9]+)\.json$ http://example.com:7071/$1_$2/$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+?)_([0-9]+)\.json$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:7071/$1/$2 [L,R]
```